# Calling a REST service keeps failing (with RESTSharp)

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm trying to talk to a REST service, and with tools like Postman or Fiddler, I'm getting the expected results just fine.

Now I'm trying to do the same from my C# code, using RestSharp 104.4.

I set up my REST client and define the user agent string, and the default `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers:

```
_restClient = new RestClient();
_restClient.UserAgent = CreateUserAgentString();
_restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
_restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Then I'm trying to call a method called `/token` to get a security token, based on HTTP Basic Auth:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(_baseServiceUrl + GetTokenUrl, Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + baseAuth);  // baseAuth contains the base Auth string
request.AddBody(request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { clientIdentifier = "Outlook", clientId = "52c600f6-262c-4fca-a4bc-e0e322e0571e" }));
```

My problem is: this resulting POST request always fails with an "internal server error":

```
Authorization: Basic .........
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: my defined user agent string
Content-Type: application/json
Host: dev.xxx.yyyyyyyy.ch
Content-Length: 90
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Body:

```
"{\"clientIdentifier\":\"Outlook\",\"clientId\":\"52c600f6-262c-4fca-a4bc-e0e322e0571e\"}"
```

The problems are several:

- I'm getting an `Accept` header that has way too many items - how can I get just `Accept: application/json` and nothing else? (as I thought setting the default header on the REST client would do)
- The settigns `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` and `Connection: Keep-Alive` also seems to cause trouble - what options/settings do I need to use on the RESTSharp client to avoid these?
- The POST body has unnecessary `"` and `\` which causes problems - how can I fix this?

Comment: Your json seems to be serialized twice. I've never used RestSharp, does `AddBody` not accept an object? I think you can pass your anonymous object without serializing explicitely.

Comment: @L.B: Adding this as an anonymous object with `AddBody` seems to be doing the trick - thank you! Convert this into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling the missing link. Following should work:

```
_restClient = new RestClient();
_restClient.BaseUrl = url;

var request = new RestRequest(_baseServiceUrl + GetTokenUrl, Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + baseAuth); 
request.AddBody(new {
    root = new { 
        clientIdentifier = "Outlook", 
        clientId = "52c600f6-262c-4fca-a4bc-e0e322e0571e" 
    }
});
```

I have used WebRequest for this in the past, I am sure, I wont be doing that again :D